How do I fix the error code 127 in this instance?
My code:
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")

I get this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/JuniorPlumpParticles/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/runner/JuniorPlumpParticles/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/runner/JuniorPlumpParticles/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/runner/JuniorPlumpParticles/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/runner/JuniorPlumpParticles/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/runner/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/127.0.6533.119/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

I was expecting that an Amazon tab would pop up.
